How to retrieve the keys from a struct that is loaded from json?
How can one read the keys from a struct that has been exported to json (without knowing in advanced what those keys are)?
E.g. file:
{
  "didNotreachInvestmentCeiling": 92,
  "didReachInvestmentCeiling": 0,
  "invalidInitialisations": 0,
  "invalidInvestments": 0,
  "investmentOverflow": 0,
  "validInitialisations": 0,
  "validInvestments": 0
}

Is read in with:
function readDataFromFile(string memory path) public  returns (bytes memory jsonData) {
    string memory fileContent = vm.readFile(path);
    jsonData = vm.parseJson(fileContent);


    string[] memory firstKeys = new string[](jsonData.length);
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < firstKeys.length; i++) {
      // This yields empty firstKeys[i] values like: ""
      emit Log("firstKeysTHEKEY=");
      emit Log(firstKeys[i]);  
    }
    
    // I do not yet know what the key is if I want to get the list of keys.
    // "hello" is not in that file, so this throws an error:
    string[] memory secondKeys = vm.parseJsonKeys(fileContent, "hello");
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < secondKeys.length; i++) {
      emit Log("THEKEY=");
      emit Log(secondKeys[i]);  
    }

    return jsonData;
  }

However, the firstKeys are empty strings, and the secondKey throws an error on the hello  key.

You need to use "$" as the second argument to parseJsonKeys function, like:
string[] memory secondKeys = vm.parseJsonKeys(fileContent, "$");

for (uint256 i = 0; i < secondKeys.length; i++) {
    emit Log("THEKEY=");
    emit Log(secondKeys[i]);
    // console.log(secondKeys[i]);
}

OUTPUT

